# Chrome Extension - Change Name in manifest.json?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Got a request to change the name of our chrome extension in manifest.json, and i'm concerned that this would break auto-updating for users with the extension already installed.

Has anyone run into this situation before regarding a name change, or am I being overly paranoid?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Changing the name doesn't break anything as updating and such is based on the extension ID.